# Reverse engineer SharePoint hash algorithm

Tags: crc

I'm trying to reverse engineer a hash algorithm used by SharePoint 2016 in MSSCrawlUrl database table. I would like to avoid discussions about the idea itself (which I agree goes against SharePoint best practices), the answer is one word: legacy.

In short, that database table contains some URLs and their hashes. SharePoint somehow calculates a hash from values in AccessUrl column (which contains URLs), and puts the result into AccessHash column. The calculation is done by unmanaged (i.e. non-.Net) code.

So far I was able to figure out the following:

1. AccessHash column definitely contains a CRC-32. In particular, the function is affine, i.e.
   hash(a ^ b ^ c) = hash(a) ^ hash(b) ^ hash(c)
   where ^ means XOR
2. I could find a generating polynomial for the hash function (or I believe I could): 0x82608EDB. I used a technique outlined in this article: http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/essays/CRC-Reverse-Engineering.html

After that I applied some brute force but couldn't figure out other algorithm parameters. The problem is a little bit more complicated because:

1. I don’t know the actual encoding that SharePoint uses when it computes hashes. I tried several in my brute force code, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something.
2. I don't have full control over the sample data, because a source string must be a valid URL (otherwise, SharePoint won't calculate a hash from it).

Here are some examples of URLs and their hashes:

```
AccessURL       AccessHash
http://a0       2141537348
http://a1      -1380154216
http://a2       -547891125
http://a4        981557741
http://a8       -169013482
http://aq       -319117100
http://aa        -55893049
```

More examples can be found in this file: https://bitbucket.org/johnnyjob/spreveng/src/master/CrcHack/Program.cs

The code which performs a brute force can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/johnnyjob/spreveng/src/master/

I'm open to any ideas, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the .net binaries responsible for creating the hash and load those in a disassembler such as JustDecompile.

Comment: @Remko I tried actually (using ILSpy), but the problem is that the hash is calculated by unmanaged (native) code.

Comment: If you wanted to look at it in a native code disassembler there are a couple of free ones.

Comment: As @Avery3R says: if you have already identified the binary, run it through a disassembler. Perhaps public symbols and or trace comments can already point you in the right direction.

Comment: Where is the binary?

Comment: @Biswapriyo The binary is part of SharePoint 2016 installation. I believe it's either mssearch.exe or mssdmn.exe process. I'm not an expert in decompiling/reading unmanaged code, so I would like to get some guidance here (if you think it will be easier than reverse engineering the algorithm as a "black box").